# Using Reactive Controls with Mat Pop-up - Angular 7

Tags: angular, dialog, components, angular-module

I am succecssfully able to pass my data from my popup to the parent component using ng-model. However with reactive forms you can't use ngModel. You have to use formcontrolname and I am unable to pass the data. From my research I am to use this.myform.input.value. but how do I do that without ngmodel. I am using this post as a reference: [how to pass data from angular material dialog to parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815455/how-to-pass-data-from-angular-material-dialog-to-parent-component)

**.HTML**

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div>
    <mat-form-field class="m-card">
        <input formControlName="input" matInput placeholder="Entry">
    </mat-form-field>


         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder=" Date" formControlName="date" [(ngModel)]="data.date">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onCancelClick()">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="data" [disabled]="addTaskForm.controls.myForm.errors">add entry</button>
 </div>
   </form>
```

**.TS**

```
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(myPopup, {
width: '500px',
data: {
  text: this.text,
  active: this.active,
  date: this.date
}
```

});

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if(result){
      this.addTask.push({displayText: result.text, effectiveDate: result.date,  isActive: result.active})
```

Comment: is just create the form in parent and pass the form as `data:{form:myForm}`, else you can use `[formGroup]="data.form"`. remember you can pass any kind of data

Comment: well the form is in the popup so I had to create the form there but let me try your other example are you saying use `[formGroup]` instead of `formControlName`

Comment: sorry, I think your problem was pass the "form". Well, If you use ReactiveForm NOT put in the same input formControlName and [(ngModel)]. Just, when create the form give value. I supouse you crfeate the form in init, so in ngOnInit, after create the form: `this.myForm.get('date').setValue(data.date)` -or when you create the form use the value data.date

Comment: do you have an example I'm not really following

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93lyze?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts. NOTE: as I get an old stackblitz, I can not use form.markAllAsTouched()

Comment: Thanks   let me test it out

Comment: what's the `object.keys` for